# python PIL and tkinter; brightening image and displaying it

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library

What I want to be able to do is open a window with two images (one image is an exact copy of the other). Then when I click a button it changes the image on the right. I hope this is making sense. The code I have no is:

```
from __future__ import division
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter
import random

class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.wm_title("Image examples")

        img = Image.open("lineage.jpg").convert("RGB")
        (w, h) = (img.size[0], img.size[1])
        print (w, h)

        tkpi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        label = Label(self.root, image=tkpi)
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)

        img2 = img.copy()
        pixels = img2.load()

        tkpi2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
        label = Label(self.root, image=tkpi2)
        label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)

        Button(self.root, text="Brighten", command=self.brighten).grid(row=0, column= 2)  
        self.root.mainloop()

    def brighten(self):
        self.pixels = self.pixels.point(lambda x: x*1.9)          
MyApp()
```

What I am trying to is have `img2` update when I click on the `brighten` button. When I try now I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\imageeditor.py", line 36, in brighten
self.pixels = self.pixels.point(lambda x: x*1.9)
AttributeError: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'pixels'
```

As you can tell I'm new to programming so any help to send me on the right track would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a complete solution that works. These are a few comments on the changes that were made:

- Previously the `__init__` method never returned because it calls self.root.mainloop() at the end. Which can cause some issues. I restructured it to be more like the hello world example in the python docs.
- There is a great [Darken/Lighten Example](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216419/darkenlighten-an-image-python) that is what the `brighten()` method is modeled around.
- there was a `from Tkinter import *`, this replaced by `from Tkinter import Frame, Tk, Label, Button`. it turns out that both PIL and Tkinter have an attribute called `Image` which was really confusing to work with. Try and avoid the use of `from module import *` and instead be explicit in what you are importing this will prevent name space collisions.

**code**

```
from Tkinter import Frame, Tk, Label, Button
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        master.wm_title("Image examples")
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.img = Image.open("lineage.jpg")
        self.photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img.convert("RGB"))
        self.label1 = Label(self, image=self.photo1)
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img.convert("RGB"))
        self.label2 = Label(self, image=self.photo2)
        self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1)

        button = Button(self, text="Brighten", command=self.brighten)
        button.grid(row=0, column=2)

    def brighten(self):
        img2 = self.img.point(lambda p: p * 1.9)
        self.photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
        self.label2 = Label(self, image=self.photo2)
        self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1)

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Comment: Seems to fix that error but gives me this back 'File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\imageeditor.py", line 32, in brighten
    self.pixels = self.pixels.point(lambda x: x*1.9)
AttributeError: 'PixelAccess' object has no attribute 'point''

Comment: yeah I tried it out, got the same error. I'm working through it now

Comment: thanks for trying, let me know if you come up with a solution.

Comment: Thank you! You're code is much cleaner and easier to understand than mine.

Answer (score 2):

I got a working one.

```
from __future__ import division
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter
import random

class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.wm_title("Image examples")

        img = Image.open("lineage.jpg").convert("RGB")
        (self.w, self.h) = (img.size[0], img.size[1])

        self.tkpi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        self.label = Label(self.root, image=self.tkpi)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)

        self.img2 = img.copy()
        self.pixels = self.img2.load()
        self.width, self.height = self.img2.size



        self.tkpi2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img2)
        self.label2 = Label(self.root, image=self.tkpi2)
        self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)

        self.btn = Button(self.root, text="Brighten")
        self.btn.grid(row=0, column= 2)
        self.btn.bind('<Button-1>', self.brighten)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def brighten(self,*args):
#        self.pixels = self.pixels.point(lambda x: x*1.9)
        for i in range(self.w):    # for every pixel:
            for j in range(self.h):
#                print self.pixels[i,j]
                self.pixels[i,j] = (int(self.pixels[i,j][0] * 1.9),
                                    int(self.pixels[i,j][1] * 1.9),
                                    int(self.pixels[i,j][2] * 1.9))
        self.tkpi2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img2)
        self.label2.configure(image = self.tkpi2)
        self.root.update_idletasks()
MyApp()
```